# Тапенад или тапенада?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно говорить "тапенад" или "тапенада"?

Answer (score 1):

Слово пока не фиксируется основными словарями, в таких случаях оба варианта можно считать правильными.

Проблема, видимо, в том, что свойственная в русском мужскому роду форма (тапенад) в языке-источнике (фр. la tapenade) имеет род женский. Поскольку при заимствованиях именно из французского тенденция следовать грамматическому роду языка-источника довольно сильная, можно предположить, что в конечном счете вариант "тапенада" победит.

Comment: Кстати, а что такое тапенад? В словарях я не нашел этого слова.

Comment: Некое кушанье, прованский салат. Встречается на кулинарных сайтах. В Вики тож есть.

Comment: О, спасибо, буду знать!)) Из меня такой кулинар, что первый раз слышу это слово)))))